# EventServiceProvider not working properly after update to laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Upgraded my project from laravel 5.1 to 5.5
It took a lot of work but mostly all issues are solved. What I couldn't find any info in the internet is about a middleware listener, in the previous laravel version it worked fine, now it doesn't

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
/**
 * The event handler mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'auth.login' => [
        LoginListener::class,
    ],
];
/**
 * Register any other events for your application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
}
```

and LoginListener class

```
class LoginListener {
    /**
     * @param \App\Models\User $user
     * @param $remember
     */
    public function handle($user, $remember) {
        die("Never comes here");
        $user->last_login = Carbon::now();
```

Edit: I fixed it and if it interests anybody if the future with the same problem, you switch 'auth.login' with 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login'

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        LoginListener::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: please add the error what is shown in the browser!

Comment: @ShafayetHossen no error shown, the event listener never actually fires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this document https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#events. From laravel version 5.2, these were some changes